# SQL Server 'invalid column name' error

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have (from the imdb database) a `casts` table and a `movie` table. I'm trying to find the name and cast size of the movie with the largest cast (distinct actors).

This is what I came up with, but I'm getting an

> "invalid column name" error on "totalcount"

Why?

Also, does this query look right?

```
select name, count(distinct pid) as totalcount 
from casts join movie on mid=movie.id 
where totalcount =
    (select max(CastCount.total) 
    from (select count(distinct pid) as total from casts group by mid)CastCount) 
group by name;
```

Comment: Is it MySQL or SQL Server question? Please use correct tags for your question.

Comment: I was under the impression that mssql server used mysql. No?

Comment: No. MSSQL Server is quite another product that has next to nothing in common with MySQL (apart the fact, that they're both SQL Relational Database Management Systems)

Comment: Ah, thanks! Yeah, this is MSSQL.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure it's MySQL...

Comment: Not unless MSSQL Server Management Studio runs off mysql.

Comment: Ok. Should be a MSSQL then ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use aliases in `WHERE`.  Since it's aggregate, you should replace it with `HAVING`:
`HAVING totalcount = ...`
Also, your subquery may return more than 1 row, and you will have another error.

Comment: Thanks! Why would I have an error though, if my subquery returned more than one row?

Comment: now I have:  select name, count(distinct pid) 
 from casts join movie on mid=movie.id 
 group by name
 having count(distinct pid) =
  (select max(CastCount.total) 
  from (select count(distinct pid) as total from casts group by mid)CastCount);

but it is returning 0 rows. Do you have any insight on why that might be?

Comment: @Colleen: you are comparing `totalcount` with the result of subquery. If the latter returns more than 1 row, `=` doesn't make sense, and you will need to use `IN(or ANY,SOME)` depends on your requirements.

Comment: hm. I changed = to in and still nothing.

Comment: If your query runs, but returns 0 records, then it obviously filters out records that don't match condition in `having` . Try running main query and subquery separately, check returning values.

Comment: running the subquery returns the same value as running select mid, count(distinct pid) from casts group by mid order by count(distinct pid) desc;, so that seems fine... why would it be filtering out those records? ONE of them HAS to match.

Comment: From what I see in your query, it will return non-empty resultset if `totalcount` equals to `max(CastCount.total)`. Maybe you want `... HAVING count(distinct pid) IN (select count(distinct pid) as total from casts group by mid)` ?

Comment: It seems to be that something about grouping by name instead of by mid is throwing it off... which I don't understand, because they should be a one-to-one relation, but... yeah.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL you can't reference an aliased column by its alias in a WHERE clause.

Your best bet is not to select where the count equals a selected max.  Instead, order by the count from high to low, and limit to the first row.

Comment: I'm not supposed to assume that there is only one.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SELECT movie.name, COUNT(casts.id) AS castsize
FROM cast
JOIN movie
ON movie.id = casts.mid
GROUP BY casts.mid
HAVING COUNT(casts.id) = MAX(COUNT(casts.id))
```

Comment: wouldn't I need a group by movie id on the max count, and can't I not do that, so don't I need a subselect?

Comment: @Colleen, there's already a `GROUP BY`, which will be used for all aggregate functions. But, you're right, I need to change the `WHERE` to `HAVING`, and it should work.